# Need to understand how wavelet is applied on Image matrix?

Tags: wavelet, image-processing

i want to understand ,how to find out Discrete wavelet transform of image 4 by 4 size using Haar wavelet on paper ?

Comment: Please explain a bit more about what you've tried.

Comment: This may give you a start. [Haar Wavelet/Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_wavelet#Haar_transform)

Answer (score 0):

Discrete Wavelet Transform is applied using Convolution.
Each variant has its own bank of filters which are applied repeatedly.
Sometimes decimation operation is applied between repetition.

A great tutorial about Wavelets in the context of Signal / Image Processing is given in [Wavelets Tour](https://wavelet-tour.github.io/).